# return "1" only once when a condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that only consists of values that are at least repeated once. I need to make it return 1 if the value is repeated once, and zero if it is repeated more than once. My column only consists of values that are at least repeated once.
example:
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
C
C
D
D

This is the formula that I'm using:
`==IF(COUNTIF($E$3:$E$111,E3)>2,"0","1")`
It returns "1" when the value has only been repeated once (like B and D in above example), and returns zero for more than that. The issue though is that it returns "1" for both Bs, but i need it to do so only once.
so it looks like this now:
A0
A0
A0
B1
B1
C0
C0
C0
C0
C0
D1
D1

but I want it to look like this:
A0
A0
A0
B1
B0
C0
C0
C0
C0
C0
D1
D0
it doesn't matter whether it returns "1" for the first B or the second, i just need it to be a single "1" to do my calculations.
What do I need to change about my formula to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

[image]

Formula for the B column:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=2,A1<>A2),1,0)
```

To adapt it for your data in E column, it should be something like this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($E$3:$E$111,E3)=2,E2<>E3),1,0)
```

You had the right idea with COUNTIF. To only display the "1" once, you also have to check whether the cell above the one that is being checked has the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking above and below.

```
=LET(
 ThisRow, ROW(E3),
 RowsAbove, ThisRow - ROW($E$3),
 RowsBelow, ROW($E$111) - ThisRow,
 IF(
  AND(
   OR(
    RowsAbove = 0,
    ISERROR(
     MATCH(
      E3,
      OFFSET($E$3,0,0,RowsAbove,1),
      0
     )
    )
   ),
   RowsBelow <> 0,
   COUNTIF(
    OFFSET(E3, 1, 0, RowsBelow, 1),
    E3
   ) = 1
  ),
  "1",
  "0"
 )
)
```

So the `OR()` is true if there are 0 matches above, the second argument of the `AND()` saves Excel from bothering to look below if it's the last row, and the third argument of the `AND()` ensures there's exactly one match below the current row.